# How to create a desktop icon for downloaded iOS apps ("Find My Friends")?

Tags: ios, applications, desktop

I've installed the Apple created "*Find My Friends*" app. It works great. But the only place I can launch it from is the *App Store* application. Every other app I've installed automatically creates a desktop icon.

How can I create a desktop icon for apps that are installed, but don't have desktop icons yet? Namely, *Find My Friends*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find My Friends on macos is not an application, per se, it is a part of the operating system and as such you access it through the Notification Center. You do, however, have to add it to the Notification Center.

Tap the notification center icon in the Mac's menu bar (top right corner) then click "Today" and then "Edit" down at the bottom. you can then add "Find My Friends." OSXDaily has [a run through](http://osxdaily.com/2016/04/22/use-find-my-friends-mac-os-x/) with screen shots.

So you **can't** install an icon for Find My friends.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was on iOS / iPhone, and not a Mac.

This is what happened:
I have a folder on my iPhone desktop called "*NeverUsed*" where I stash apps that I expect to never use, such as: *AppleWatch, iBook,* and *Health*. I had also placed *FindFriends* in that folder and forgot about it.

I googled how to grep the iPhone which is done by touching the desktop and dragging down.  So, I grepped for "Find Friends" and there it was in the *NeverUsed* folder.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are on a desktop so this answer wouldn't be applicable.

Comment: @fsb I just used the term "Desktop" incorrectly. I am not sure what to call the UI state of an iPhone when an app is not running. I interpreted the classic row of icons as a "desktop".